# UDP Client and Server Buffer Agreement

Tags: udp, client-server

Hi I am writing a program that will send a file from client to server using UDP socket using different packet sizes for example 512B, 1KB and 2KB and i don't want use fixed buffer size in the receiver(server).I need some codes in Java that will allow both server and client to agree upon a packet size before transfer start. Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried? As is, your question is too general: Stack Overflow is not a place where you go to ask others to do your work.

Comment: Is my course work. I tried using fixed buffer size and when I send a packet size that is larger than prefix size at the receiver the packet cannot be transferred.I need your help

Answer (score 1):

Don't you forget that UDP packets may be fragmented, duplicated and lost? There is a whole bunch of things to take care of, starting with lost packet retransmissions.

I hate to give a "don't do this" kind of answers, but for this one, just use TCP. And if you want some user-level "packets", you can have them with TCP also (prefix each one with its length, that's enough).

Comment: Is my course work and is based on UDP socket. I need your assistance